# Heroku No Such Account Error

Tags: heroku

To start:
I am able to log in to heroku with my email and password.

When logging into heroku through my terminal using the same email and password credentials I get the following error.

```
heroku login
Email: myemail@email.com
Password:
No such account: myemail@email.com
```

Comment: you should put a request to heroku support... hopefully they are tht right guys to figure this problem.

Answer (score 14):

check your `[Project Root]/.git/config`
There are some `heroku accounts specific` settings:

```
[heroku]
    account = <account name>
```

you can delete those two lines and then try to login again
Just save what you delete :)

Answer (score 5):

Try to remove the existing account credentials `rm -rf ~/.heroku/plugins/heroku-accounts` and do `heroku login` enter your credentials

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure you have the latest version of the heroku gem/toolbelt installed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.git/config` for references to remotes like 'git@heroku.account' and remove those.

Also, check your `~/.ssh/config` for references to that 'account' and take them out.

Then, re-do your auth `heroku auth:logout` and `heroku auth:login` and maybe `heroku keys:add` to get everything set back up.

Comment: Removing references in `~/.ssh/config` and doing `heroku keys:add` at the end is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is a conflict between Heroku toolbelt and the Heroku gem. I also had the same problem. Read this article to solve it - http://bit.ly/1sku20D